# Excluding a specific IP from vpn tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

So I bought a vpn service, I got it's .ovpn file, and now I run it like this:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/ovpn
```

But I am connected to a certain network that has a local website with a domain of `foo.bar:3000`

So I thought I should ping it to get it's i.p., example its ip is `1.2.3.4`

Now I wanted to exempt that local website, so I can still access it when connected to the vpn.

I've read a bit, like 2 hrs now, and pointed me that I could add this line to the `.ovpn` file

```
route "1.2.3.4 255.255.255.4 4.5.6.7"
```

Where `4.5.6.7` is from `ip route show`

```
default via 4.5.6.7 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100
```

I have little no knowledge about this kind of stuff, what do you think is a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the Netmask wrong.
Netmask depends upon the private IP ranges you use, hence if your private ip range is 192.168.1.1-254 then netmask should be 255.255.255.0

Updated route configuration :

```
route foo.bar 255.255.255.0 {your-default-gateway}
route 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0 {your-default-gateway}
```

To find out what your default gateway IP address is, first disconnect from VPN and follow this [Guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-gateway-ip-address/).

Note : Depending on IP address of domain `foo.bar`, the netmask would change.
Hence try with other netmask(255.255.0.0 and 255.0.0.0) if above configuration doesn't work.